# Licensing users in Visual Studio Team Foundation Services

Tags: azure, team-foundation-server, visual-studio

## Background

We have a VSTS instance which is connected to an Azure Subscription to enable payment for those users requiring the `Basic` role (i.e. beyond the 5 free accounts, and anyone covered by MSDN, or using the free Stakeholder access).  Our VSTS instance is not linked to AD, whilst our Azure instance is.  VSTS is linked to our Azure subscription solely for billing purposes.

Historically I've gone to the Azure portal to amend the number of licenses assigned, then to the VSTS user management screen to assign the licenses; cumbersome, but it works (rather: it worked).

Today one of our developers who'd previously been assigned a Basic license contacted me to say they could not login; looking at VSTS their license showed as `⛔ Basic`, and the User Summary section showed `⛔ Invalid 3`; i.e. stating that 3 users had this issue.

Looking at the Azure portal, our VSTS accounts section no longer showed.
However checking VSTS the Azure subscription was still associated.
The link to add more licenses from VSTS goes to the Visual Studio Marketplace (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/acquisition?itemName=ms.vss-vstsuser).  Here I can request users, but don't have access to create them.  Rather it triggers a mail requesting approval (from me).  I think the reason for this is our Azure instance uses my Organization account, whilst my VSTS instance uses a Microsoft account (with the same account name; since this pre-existed our organisation migrating to O365).  I can't find a way to use the approval link provided in that mail under my Organization account; it seems that only my Microsoft account can log into the marketplace; and that's the account which does not have suitable Azure access.

## Question

Does anyone know how to assign new licenses to VSTS when VSTS uses a Microsoft Accounts and Azure uses Organization Accounts (and more specifically / if relevant, both accounts have the same username).

Comment: NB: Also posted question to VS Dev Community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/167030/unable-to-add-user-licenses-for-vsts-through-azure.html

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there was on issue around the account creation today https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/?p=15625
It appears to be resolved now, but that service blog is a good place to check when troubleshooting VSTS issues that may be temporary/working befoe

Comment: Thank-you for the link to that blog; I wasn't aware of that resource.  Sadly it seems this one wasn't the cause of my issue, as the symptoms described are slightly different to what I'm experiencing, and also I'm still having issues whilst the above is now resolved.  Thanks again for suggesting though.